# How to show a property from gradle.properties on the UI

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have a spring boot application, and I am using angular for the frontend and gradle as the build tool. I have defined the version of my application in gradle.properties file like this — `version=2.0.0`.

I want to show this version somewhere in the UI. How do I do this?

Comment: Run gradle saveVersion and save version.txt in the angular dist folder. In the frontend read version.txt file for version.
`task saveVersion()  {
    doLast {
        new File(projectDir, "version.txt").text = """ 
                            Version: $version
                            """
    }
}`